# Not sure why I'm getting red lined here

Tags: java, user-interface, inputstream

I'm creating something with GUI and binary IO and I'm getting red lined here when using InputStream.

I have created a new Object, Buffered and File InputStream as in.
when I use in.readUTF, in.readDouble, in.readObject why am I getting red lined?

Thanks in advance!

```
public RecordViewerPanel() throws IOException {
    initComponents();
    try{ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                              new BufferedInputStream(
                              new FileInputStream(filename)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RecordViewerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
}

private void refreshUI() {
    SalesAgent sale = (customer.get(curIndex));
    firstTextField.setText(sale.getFirst());
    lastTextField.setText(sale.getLast());
    salesTextField.setText("$" + String.valueOf(sale.getSales()));
    dateTextField.setText(String.valueOf(sale.getDate()));
    recordPanel.repaint();
}

ArrayList<SalesAgent> salesForce = new ArrayList<SalesAgent>();
String first = in.readUTF();
String last = in.redUTF();
double sales = in.readDouble();
Date date = (Date)(in.readObject());
```

Comment: What in the world is *red lined*?

Comment: Sorry haha, I'm getting a red line under in on all of those statements, an error. Cannot find variable in.

Comment: ```in``` doesn't seem to be in the same scope, but I'm not sure where that dangling code block is.

Comment: Wouldn't `ObjectInputStream in` declared in the `try{}` fall out of scope after that, so you would get errors trying to access it? (Honest question, since I don't use try/catch very often.)

Comment: @Serlite code blocks in Java are scoping blocks in that variables declared in them only exist in them.

Comment: Full code for the class would be helpful. It's difficult to say anything meaningful about what you've shown us.

Comment: Next to the red line is a message saying what the problem is. What does that say? And is it unclear to you what it means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is declared within `RecordViewerPanel()`. Its scope is within the `{}` for the `try/catch` block. Hence in the following line:

```
String first = in.readUTF();
```

`in` is not something that is recognized by Java which is the reason for the error message `Cannot find variable in`.

You can fix this problem by passing `in` around or by declaring it such that it is within the scope of where it is being called or used.

Also fix the following line:

```
String last = in.redUTF();
```

to

```
String last = in.readUTF();
```

Again though, make sure `in` is in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Quick look, but isn't this:

```
String last = in.redUTF();
```

Supposed to be this:

```
String last = in.readUTF();
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually two-fold here, you've got your 'in' variable declared inside of a try/catch block, which means it is not accessible further down (where you try to make use of it). Actually, it's also declared within the scope of another method, which means it could never be visible to that block below. The code you've pasted doesn't actually look valid, as you can't have function declarations inside of other functions in Java (with the exception of anonymous classes). Additionally, you've got a typo with your 'last' variable, should be in.readUTF(); instead of redUTF().

Answer (score 0):

Your input is declared inside of the try catch and youre accessing it outside of that scope.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @bjb568, while this answer isn't terribly lengthy, it does answer the question. I'm not sure where you're going with this comment.

Comment: @shortstuffsushi You like sushi and short answers? Huh… Anyway, it's best as a comment, even if it does technically answer the question.

Comment: Yeah it is reasonably brief but even by your own admission @bjb568 it does answer the question. I should have more effort into helping but I was in the lift on the way back to work so there was limited time. My bad.

Comment: Can users with scores this low actually comment? I thought that was something that you eventually unlocked.